# Can't reset filter after clearing input ( react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

Have filter, it's filtering ok, but when clear input. I see filtered result:

```
filterList(event) {
    var updatedList = this.state.items;
    if (event.target.value !== '') {
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
  }
    this.setState({items: updatedList});  // now this.state.items has a value
   }
```

My condition not working.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dPZM9BZVa4uzEMwdNpZ8?p=catalogue full component in script.js

Comment: can you show where is this function called in code?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dPZM9BZVa4uzEMwdNpZ8?p=catalogue full component in script.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better approach for this. You usually don't want to use props to set your state directly. What you want is to only use the state for filtered item sets, since your props will always contain the full set of items. So first, remove your `componentWillReceiveProps` function. Then change the following things:

```
// in your constructor
this.state = {
  filteredItems: false
}

filterList(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;

  this.setState({
    filteredItems: !value
      ? false
      : this.props.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
  })
}

// inside render
var elems = this.state.filteredItems || this.props.items
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'value' of null Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 5, pending 4)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the ```item``` inside the filter function. Answer edited.

Comment: Try again, not helps

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to writing arrow functions. I forgot to return a new object that had the items value. Edited answer, try again.

Comment: warning.js:36 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist() not helps ((

Comment: when clear input, result not changing, see filtered result

Comment: ncaught ReferenceError: allItems is not defined

Comment: allItems - What must be there try this.state.items not helps

Comment: Sorry, your initial approach was the problem. I've changed the answer to show a cleaner approach that utilizes props and state appropriately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134202/discussion-between---and-shadymoses).

Comment: Now works, but I try find 1 element, and show all exept first, works reverse

Comment: need add !== -1

Comment: Edited answer to add the correct condition. Glad it's working for you